# What are the differences between different versions of RS485?

Tags: rs485

I'm trying to find out the best order an `RS485` interface as an optional interface for my `CX2033` `Beckhoff` industrial PC. in the ordering page I faced the following four details of `RS485` with some strange expressions:

drop/end point

with/without echo

termination on/off

```
RS485 interface, D-sub socket, 9-pin, configuration as an end point, without echo, termination on
RS485 interface, D-sub socket, 9-pin, configuration as an end point, with echo, termination on
RS485 interface, D-sub socket, 9-pin, configuration as drop point, without echo, termination off
RS485 interface, D-sub socket, 9-pin, configuration as drop point, with echo, termination off
```

I looked up on the internet for these phrases I almost find nothing about them. now I have some questions:

1. What is the meaning of these phrases in the `RS485` interface?
2. What does mean the word `configuration as`, configure as hardware or software? and are there changeable to each other after this configuration or not?

more information is available on this [link](https://www.beckhoff.com/en-en/products/ipc/embedded-pcs/cx20x3-amd-ryzen/cx2033.html):

```
Product information->Options->Optional interfaces
```

all datasheets of this PC are also available on this page.

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you please add the name of the part and a link to the datasheet?

Comment: @Ilya the question is edited and the link is added.

Comment: Termination in rs485 means additional resistance to increase the range. See details here https://e2e.ti.com/blogs_/b/analogwire/posts/rs-485-basics-when-termination-is-necessary-and-how-to-do-it-properly. In echo mode channel will reply with the bytes received. Read details here https://control.com/forums/threads/echo-mode.14279/

Answer (score 1):

The `echo` is can be a feature or a bug. As explained [here](https://control.com/forums/threads/echo-mode.14279/#js-post-101298), `Some CPU use this as a form of "timing control"` but it can create standing waves on the line which may create an undesirable behavior.

`Termination` and `drop-point` are essentially the opposite one from another. Either there is aa built-in termination or there is no termination and an option for you to add it. It is very much depends on your network topology. You can read about it [here](https://www.cuidevices.com/blog/rs-485-serial-interface-explained) and [here](https://know.innon.com/bias-termination-rs485-network).